# How to limit amount of foreing key per record

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have 3 tables Title, Detail, TypeDetail, and I need to add the foreign key or rule, constraints, etc. How can I control the amount of Details per Title, it only can have detail of each type.

I tried with foreign keys.

My tables

```
Create table Title(
TitleID int identity(1,1) primary Key not null)

Create table Type(
TypeID int identity(1,1) primary Key not null)

Create table Detail(
DetailID int identity(1,1) primary Key not null,
TitleID int REFERENCES Title(TitleID),
TypeID int REFERENCES Type(TypeID))
```

Data in Title

```
TitleID
1
2
```

Data in Type

```
TypeID
1
2
3
```

Data in Detail

```
DetailID|TitleID|TypeID
1|1|1
2|1|2
3|1|3
4|2|1
5|2|2
6|1|1 // cant because I all ready inserted the Type 1 for Title 1
```

I want to make this restrction. Smoe help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a unique constraint:

```
create table Detail (
    DetailID int identity(1,1) primary Key not null,
    TitleID int REFERENCES Title (TitleID),
    TypeID int REFERENCES Type (TypeID),
    constraint unq_detail_title_type unique (Title, Type)
);
```

This will not allow duplicate pairs in the table.